# Loop over AWS Glue Dynamic Frame to get keys, values or to create a List/Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-glue

I have written a Python Glue script to read 2 CSV files and get the information. First CSV has complete student information (**student_id, student_name, city, sex)**, second CSV is basically a "**definitions**" file which have few columns which identify what to do with the data in the first CSV: example of a record from "definitions" file:

```
col_name, modification_type, modify_column** <--HEADER
student_id,0** <-- ROW
student_name,0
city,0
address,0
sex,1
student_status,2,old_status
```

Below is a snip of my Glue script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, LongType
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

studentDataset="s3://mybucket/file1.csv"
modificationDataset="s3://mybucket/file2.csv"

dynaframe_student = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
connection_type="s3",
format="csv",
connection_options={
"paths": [studentDataset]
},

dynaframe_modifications = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
connection_type="s3",
format="csv",
connection_options={
"paths": [modificationDataset]
},

l_transformations = dynaframe_modifications.toDF() 
df_keys = dynaframe_modifications.keys() <<-- error here

for col_name in dynaframe_modifications .keys(): <<-- error here
m_df = dynaframe_modifications(col_name)
print("DFNAME==>" + col_name)
print("FULLTRA==>" + dynaframe_modifications(col_name))
pprint(m_df)
```

now my challenge is how to loop over the "**dynaframe_modifications**" and pull just the header
and later as required pull the keys and values so that I can create a List that holds all the "**col_name**" pertaining to "**modification_type**" 0 or 1 or 2 which can be later used to select/drop/rename columns from the "dynaframe_student" student dynamicFrame.

I tried converting the dataframe to DF using **toDF()** and calling **keys()** doesn't work:

```
l_transformations = dynaframe_modifications.toDF()
df_keys = dynaframe_modifications.keys()

for col_name in dynaframe_modifications .keys():
m_df = dynaframe_modifications(col_name)
print("DFNAME==>" + col_name)
print("FULLTRA==>" + dynaframe_modifications(col_name))
pprint(m_df)
```

I want to get the keys and there values so that I can create the following List->Dictionary datastructure which can be looked up to selectFields/drop/rename from the StudentDataframe.

```
('xformcode', 0),
              ('subset',
               ('column_name', 'student_id'),
                             ('xform_column_name', nan)),
                ('column_name', 'student_name'),
                             ('xform_column_name', nan),
                ('column_name', 'city'),
                             ('xform_column_name', nan),
                ('column_name', 'address'),
                             ('xform_column_name', nan)])],
 ('xformcode', 1),
              ('subset',
               ('column_name', 'sex'),
                             ('xform_column_name', nan)]),
('xformcode', 2),
              ('subset',
               ('column_name', 'student_status'),
                             ('xform_column_name', 'old_status')])]
```

and looping over it also errors out with the below error :
**AttributeError: 'DynamicFrame' object has no attribute 'keys'**

I came across a DynamicFrameCollection class but not sure which package to use: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-collection.html][1]

is this class available within the "awsglue.dynamicframe" package?
Any help from the forum members is deeply appreciated.

Comment: In your code you have `l_transformations` which is the variable you should be running the `keys()` function against.

Of course, that wouldn't work because `keys()` is not a valid method in a Dataframe -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html

You might actually want to use `items()` instead which is native to python lists